# How to bind a keyboard shortcut to the play and pause controls of the html audio element

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, html5-audio

This is what I thought should work but it doesn't. I'm am using unicode 112 for the "p" key and 115 for "s".

```html
var audio = document.getElementById("lessonTrack");
window.addEventListener("keypress", playPauseKb, false);

function playPauseKb() {
  var x = event.keycode;
  if (x == 112) {
    audio.play();
  }
  else if (x == 115) {
    audio.pause();
  }
}
```

Comment: please can you show us your code on https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I've added "o" shortcut to return to beginning of audio track. https://jsfiddle.net/tciprop/9uw9jh1x/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the right idea. I added some debugging steps that you can take in the future to help you trouble shoot your code. You just have to remove the comments for testing. I also added the missing event parameter to your function. I changed the event to keyup but you can use another event if you choose, however some keyboard buttons will not respond to key down events.

You should also try and get in the habbit of using `===` instead of `==` when you can it will help prevent some possible bugs in the future. The `==` operator will match the value but the `===` operator will match the value and type.  This can be a problem if you want to make sure your value is a string,number,etc.

**Update:** You might want use the following line of code in place of the original line to check for keypress events in firefox because it will return 0 for event.keyCode.

```
//check to see which event property is supported
var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
```

JavaScript:

```
var audio = document.getElementById("lessonTrack");

window.addEventListener("keyup", playPauseKb, false);

function playPauseKb(event) {//<-- added missing event parameter


  var x = event.keyCode;

  //debug
  //console.log(x);

  //p on the keyboard
  if (x === 80) {

    audio.play();

    //alert("playing");

  } else if (x === 83) { //s button keycode

    audio.pause();

    //alert("paused");

  }
}
```

Comment: Works out of the box! Thanks very much.

Comment: @Phil No problem I am glad I could help. Check out my update if you get a chance.  When I was testing your orginal code in fire fox I noticed that the keypress event returned 0.

Comment: Thanks agaIn. I knew about the Firefox issue but just wanted to make it work in Chrome first. But that's a very helpful update.

Comment: Actually, both "keyCode" and "which" are now depreciated. Yet, it's still a nice answer and I've up voted.

Comment: Thank you, nice catch. Too much JQuery on my brain. I gave you an upvote as well.

Comment: Disregard my earlier comment as you were completely correct. My updated answer explains why.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following: Looks like you have the wrong call to keyCode, javascript is case sensitive so keycode is not the same as keyCode

```
var audio = document.getElementById("lessonTrack");
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
var x = e.keyCode;
if (x === 80) { // pressed 'p'
  audio.play();
} else if (x === 83) { // pressed 's'
  audio.pause();
}
});
```

Comment: of course be sure you enclose this inside document.ready or window.onload

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

Mozilla tells us to use *event.key* because *event.charCode* and *event.which* are depreciated. Yet, this is misleading as *event.key* is only used in newer versions of Firefox and IE. Chrome, Opera, and perhaps others do not support it. Actually, *event.which* appears to be the most widely supported. So, per Larry Lane's answer, we should continue to use:

```
var code = event.which || event.charCode;
```

It's also important to know that keypress may return a different char code than keydown and keypress.  For example, pressing "p" will return 112 ("p") in keypress and 80 ("P") in keydown/keyup. So use keypress when trying to capture the actual char. Use keydown/keyup when you need to capture special keys like alt, ctrl, shift, etc.

I've updated the demo code to better illustrate the differences.

**Original:**

The most important point for OP is to include the event parameter in the handler function. If omitted, as in the original code, none of the solutions here will work.

Also, both keyCode and charCode are [depreciated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress) and only worked with the keypress event. OP should instead use event.key which returns a character and use event.key.charCodeAt(0) to get the code if that is required.

Here is a snippet to show the various keyboard events:

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  k('keypress-charCode', e.charCode);
  k('keypress-which', e.which);
  k('keypress-key', e.key);
  k('keypress-char', String.fromCharCode(e.charCode || e.which || e.key))
}, false);

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  k('keydown-charCode', e.charCode);
  k('keydown-which', e.which);
  k('keydown-key', e.key);
  k('keydown-char', String.fromCharCode(e.charCode || e.which || e.key))
}, false);

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  k('keyup-charCode', e.charCode);
  k('keyup-which', e.which);
  k('keyup-key', e.key);
  k('keyup-char', String.fromCharCode(e.charCode || e.which || e.key))
}, false);

k('navigator', 'Navigator: ' + navigator.appName + ' / ' + navigator.appCodeName);


function k(id, value) {
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = value || '<i>undefined</i>';
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 20em;
}
td {
  border: 1px lightgray solid;
  padding: 4px;
}
td i {
  color: red;
}
caption {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: steelblue;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigator"></div>
<br>
<table id="test">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>charCode</td>
    <td>which</td>
    <td>key</td>
    <td>char</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>keypress</td>
    <td id="keypress-charCode"></td>
    <td id="keypress-which"></td>
    <td id="keypress-key"></td>
    <td id="keypress-char"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>keydown</td>
    <td id="keydown-charCode"></td>
    <td id="keydown-which"></td>
    <td id="keydown-key"></td>
    <td id="keydown-char"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>keyup</td>
    <td id="keyup-charCode"></td>
    <td id="keyup-which"></td>
    <td id="keyup-key"></td>
    <td id="keyup-char"></td>

  </tr>
</table>

<p>* press a key to view result
```

Comment: Thanks. I've checked W3C and it says event.key is only supported in Firefox & IE9+. It doesn't work for me in Chrome.

Comment: @Phil - Thanks for info. Tested and found also fails in Opera. Will update my answer. Up voted your question.